# DraggableScrollableSheet snap to top before scrolling

Tags: flutter

Looking for help with the draggable scrollable sheet. Atm if you flick the sheet up, the scroll activates straight away, and if you do a strong flick, the list scrolls until momentum stops. But what I'd like is an example where the list doesn't scroll when you flick up and the sheet just snaps to the top, and only then does the list become scrollabled, there after.

Answer (score 1):

There is an oppen issue for adding snap behaviour to the DraggableScrollableSheet: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34111